custom kubelet configuration not applied on in karpenter node with EKS | karpenter v: 0.37.0 & eks cluster v:1.30
==> ec2nodeclass.yaml
apiVersion: karpenter.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: EC2NodeClass
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  amiFamily: AL2
  role: "KarpenterNodeRole-eks-karpenter"
  subnetSelectorTerms:
    - tags:
        karpenter.sh/discovery: "eks-karpenter"
  securityGroupSelectorTerms:
    - tags:
        karpenter.sh/discovery: "eks-karpenter"

==>nodepool.yaml
apiVersion: karpenter.sh/v1beta1
kind: NodePool
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      requirements:
        - key: kubernetes.io/arch
          operator: In
          values: ["amd64"]
        - key: kubernetes.io/os
          operator: In
          values: ["linux"]
        - key: karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-category
          operator: In
          values: ["c", "m", "r"]
        - key: karpenter.k8s.aws/instance-generation
          operator: Gt
          values: ["2"]
      nodeClassRef:
        apiVersion: karpenter.k8s.aws/v1beta1
        kind: EC2NodeClass
        name: default
      kubelet:
        systemReserved:
          cpu: "100m"
          memory: "200Mi"
        kubeReserved:
          cpu: "100m"
          memory: "200Mi"
        evictionHard:
          memory.available: "200Mi"
          nodefs.available: "10%"
          nodefs.inodesFree: "5%"
        evictionMaxPodGracePeriod: 60
        imageGCHighThresholdPercent: 85
        imageGCLowThresholdPercent: 75
        maxPods: 110
  limits:
    cpu: 1000
  disruption:
    consolidationPolicy: WhenUnderutilized
    expireAfter: 720h

==>scaled worker node kubelet-config.json
cat /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json
{
  "kind": "KubeletConfiguration",
  "apiVersion": "kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "address": "0.0.0.0",
  "authentication": {
    "anonymous": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "webhook": {
      "cacheTTL": "2m0s",
      "enabled": true
    },
    "x509": {
      "clientCAFile": "/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"
    }
  },
  "authorization": {
    "mode": "Webhook",
    "webhook": {
      "cacheAuthorizedTTL": "5m0s",
      "cacheUnauthorizedTTL": "30s"
    }
  },
  "clusterDomain": "cluster.local",
  "hairpinMode": "hairpin-veth",
  "readOnlyPort": 0,
  "cgroupDriver": "systemd",
  "cgroupRoot": "/",
  "featureGates": {
    "RotateKubeletServerCertificate": true
  },
  "protectKernelDefaults": true,
  "serializeImagePulls": false,
  "serverTLSBootstrap": true,
  "tlsCipherSuites": [
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305",
    "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384",
    "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
  ],
  "clusterDNS": [
    "10.100.0.10"
  ],
  "evictionHard": {
    "memory.available": "100Mi",
    "nodefs.available": "10%",
    "nodefs.inodesFree": "5%"
  },
  "kubeReserved": {
    "cpu": "80m",
    "ephemeral-storage": "1Gi",
    "memory": "893Mi"
  },
  "providerID": "aws:///us-east-2c/i-09342fe6aa1715f51",
  "systemReservedCgroup": "/system",
  "kubeReservedCgroup": "/runtime"
}

just for quick notice==> i added kubelet custom configuration
      kubelet:
        systemReserved:
          cpu: "100m"
          memory: "200Mi"
        kubeReserved:
          cpu: "100m"
          memory: "200Mi"
        evictionHard:
          memory.available: "200Mi"
          nodefs.available: "10%"
          nodefs.inodesFree: "5%"
        evictionMaxPodGracePeriod: 60
        imageGCHighThresholdPercent: 85
        imageGCLowThresholdPercent: 75
        maxPods: 110

same thing not seen in kubelet-config.json after created node by karpenter(when pod scaled)
I tried with same above configuration on my EKS cluster. expecting to help me to someone solve my problem.

Have you checked with amiFamily supports your kubelet conf ?

I am using AL2 ami family
